# Tightening soldered male fitting - joint stress

Tags: plumbing, copper-pipe

I need to expose a male fitting to connect to a supply line.

I can do this:
[image]

But I am concerned, when a person tightens the supply line don't they risk stressing the soldered joint even if they are using two plumbing wrenches?

I'm worried the rotational stress will fracture the joint -- should I not be? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: One wrench is used for tightening, the second wrench is used to hold the work solid, so should not be any stress passed to the solder joint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that connection is soldered correctly there will need to be a great amount of force to fracture the joint.  To cause any problem for that matter.
Clean the surfaces, apply flux and use lead free solder. heat the pipe/ fitting, not the solder.  You'll be good.

Comment: 2 minor comments:  1)  I don't think solder with lead in it even available any more, so unless somebody has really old stock, that shouldn't be a worry. 2) a good friend of mine is a plumber and once said that flux gets old and after being opened for over a year, it should be trashed and buy new flux.

Comment: Good info George,  Based on the OPs question I don't think they have plumbing supplies laying around unused . I don't know where in the world they are, but there are some places that still sell anything.  You know the drill. If you don't cover the base , someone trips on it and blames you....so I hear ya.

Comment: Thank you both! USA, and yes bought flex last week.